# PHP array to json with filtering

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am using `Codeigniter` and I want map(filter) values from selection.
For example I have some query like `SELECT * FROM users` and I want map only `first_name` and `last_name` not all N columns. 
Does it exist some libs or mapping/filtering tool where I can specify template for mapping?

Comment: You can select the required fields from database like `SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users`

Comment: @Scorpion bad idea, because I need each time care about SELECT statement. I want select always the same, perform some manipulations and then map json.

Comment: put you code and what is your expected O/P

Comment: @Irfan I think that no need for code here. I found that to solve my problem I need something like `Datamapper ORM` but it looks too old and I am not able to download this lib :(